# Keep getting errors while using express and yarn

Tags: node.js, hadoop-yarn

I tried running a file using Yarn start but I got this error.

```
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event

Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\\Users\\thede.console-ninja\\trace.log'
Emitted 'error' event on \_0x36ecab instance at:
at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
errno: -4048,
code: 'EPERM',
syscall: 'open',
path: 'C:\\Users\\thede\\.console-ninja\\trace.log'
}
```